# How to configure diaspora as my own app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, social-networking, diaspora

Hey guys I had installed the latest version of diaspora on my Ubuntu 13.10 PC with rails 4.1.2 and ruby 2.0.0 everything is working good but I want to change the name of the app from diaspora to something else.is it possible to do so.I am new to rails please help if u can.Thanks

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: rails 4.1.2 ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up `config/diaspora.yml`
2. Search for the key `pod_name` in the `settings` section
3. Change value to whatever you want and save the file
4. Restart diaspora*

Ps. OT note, Ubuntu 13.10 is no longer supported by Canonical - you should upgrade ;)

Comment: hey Jaywink tnx for helping me i followed what you said but i get this error



`ahmed@ahmed-desktop:~/diaspora$ ./script/server
/home/ahmed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (/home/ahmed/diaspora/config/diaspora.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 30 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)`

Comment: @AhmedReza YAML files are strict on the indendation. Make sure that you keep the indendation to exactly 2 spaces and also make sure your pod name is understood as a string to YAML. Check this: http://docs.ansible.com/YAMLSyntax.html

Comment: thanks @Jaywink for helping me once again but as i had mentioned in my question i am new to rails and ruby.so can u please explain me the whole process if you don't mind.??

right now my settings in`diaspora.yml` is

`     General settings
  settings:  Section

       Pod name (default="firm*")
       The pod name displayed in various locations, including the header.
     pod_name: "firm*`

Comment: @AhmedReza It's impossible to help without seeing the file. Please mask all secret keys etc if you have any in there and post it to pastebin.com and a link here :)

Comment: i had posted the whole diaspora.yml file as before and after adding my pod name...check it out http://pastebin.com/DwRvUXsg

Comment: You uncommented the explanation of the setting, please read the top of the file carefully, it explains what to uncomment and what not in length.

Comment: @AhmedReza hint - you accidently commented out lines (in pastebin) 1005, 1008, 1009